Hiveでカラムをmapで出力した際に「C000007」など整列されたカラム番号の文字列として出力される
まず権限がないためsql,phpカテゴリの枠をお借りしますことをお許しください。
下記ページの回答にある解決策で問題の一部が解決したのですが、"" で囲まれた部分の出力に苦しんでいます。
ここではX1と出力されることが期待されますが、私の環境ではC000007等整列されたカラム番号として文字列で出力されてしまいます。
このことについて解決方法あれば是非教えていただけませんか？
参考にしたページ:
Converting columns to rows (UNPIVOT) in hiveql - Stack Overflow

select column1, column2, column3, m_key, m_val from
    (select column1, column2, column3, map("X1", X1, "X2", X2, "X3", X3, "X4", X4) as map1
    from table1) as t1
lateral view explode(map1) xyz as m_key, m_val    



Apache Hive に関する質問で合っていますか？いずれにせよ、タイトルに [タグ名] のような形式でタグを含めるのは避けてください。参考ヘルプ https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

申し訳ございません。以後気を付けます。
